# Can't mkdir events No space left on device - EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

After put about 5 millions files on a EC2 instance, I can no longer mkdir because inodes are all used. I still have 40Gb space on this EBS! Is there a way to overcome this?
Thanks.

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse%  
/dev/xvda1     5242880 5234036   0     100% /
```

Can I add another volume to the EC2 instance and put other 5 million files there? ( I have 10 mil files).

Comment: i've been using `btrfs` lately for issues like this (i have about 37 million files on one).  that already answer is **old**.  a newer solution would be suggested these days.